# It is possible to show centered the loading animated circle of the progress Dialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm creating a progressDialog without tittle and without body text, it shows only the loading animated circle.

```
progress_dialog = ProgressDialog.show( activity, "" , "", false );
```

Is it possible to show centered the loading animated circle of the progress Dialog?

Now, the circle appears with left alignment.

Comment: Sorry for my previous question. Did you try `setProgressStyle()`?

Comment: no, wich parameter i have to pass to achieve my needs?

Comment: I didn't find a way to use it. However, you can try [this method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog). Replace `custom_dialog.xml` code with a one root RelativeLayout and put a spinning wheel inside it with attribute `android:layout_centerInParent` set to true. This is how I'll do it. What you need to find out about is how to reference the spinning wheel(i.e. the ProgressDialog wheel) into the xml file

Answer (score 0):

simply extend the basic Dialog class and put in your own rotated drawable/layout as you want.

here is a nice example how it works: [Link](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-display-custom-dialog-and.html)